# How do I catch that enter is pressed in Polymer 1.0 paper-input

Tags: polymer

How do I catch when <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed in Polymer 1.0 `paper-input`?

I tried with the `on-bind-value-changed` that is exposed through the `iron-input`, but it seems it only differentiates with letters in the event argument where `e.detail` is `null` on all other keys, such as <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd>, etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would bind a `keydown` event to the input that called a function. In there you can find which key was pressed. For example:

```
<dom-module id="test-element">
    <template>
        <!-- add keydown listener to paper input -->
        <paper-input label="Input label" on-keydown="checkForEnter"></paper-input>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "test-element",
            checkForEnter: function (e) {
                // check if 'enter' was pressed
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                    // enter pressed!
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Ah, this is just the normal input tag event firing ... didn't know that these were available. Awesome :-) ... thanks

Comment: use e.which instead of deprecated keyCode property

Comment: Is better option to use e.key property, it returns a more readable value. In this case it would return 'Enter'.

Answer (score 13):

Another possibility would be to use `iron-a11y-keys`. That way, you could declaratively define what's happening when the user presses the `enter` key while the focus is on the `paper-input` element.

Example (copied from the Polymer Catalog):

```
<iron-a11y-keys id="a11y" target="[[target]]" keys="enter"
                on-keys-pressed="onEnter"></iron-a11y-keys>
<paper-input id="input" placeholder="Type something. Press enter. Check console." value="{{userInput::input}}"></paper-input>
```

After that, you will have to bind the `target` property of the `a11y` element to the `paper-input` element, like so:

```
...
properties: {
  userInput: {
    type: String,
    notify: true,
  },
  target: {
    type: Object,
    value: function() {
      return this.$.input;
    }
  },
},
onEnter: function() {
  console.log(this.userInput);
}
...
```

Hope that helps. See [iron-a11y-keys](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-a11y-keys) for more information.

Comment: Are there actual a11y benefits to this approach that would make it preferred over the accepted answer?

Comment: @BennyPowers I'm not aware of specific benefits other than the ones mentioned in https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#kbd_general_binding (also linked from the iron-a11y-keys component page)